# Different Android Screens, Different colors, can we program screens to look the same?

Tags: android, dynamic, themes, display

Is it possible to have a dynamic color scheme that adjusts to the type of display each device has? Greys between screens can look different and I am wondering if there is an efficient way to create similar looks between the colors of screens.

Answer (score 0):

catch the screen oration and create a color .

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        float oration = height / width;

      Color backgroundColor = new Color();
      backgroundColor.red(Math.abs(Integer.valueOf((String.valueOf(oration)))*10));
    ........
```

Comment: can you explain more on how dividing the height/width will give me a factor for the visual scale of the color that we see on the screen?